# Google Workspace, SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar causes "TransportError", with Error code = 10, Path = /wardeninit and google.script.run will fail

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to make a Google App script with this simple code below

```
function onInstall(e) {
  onOpen(e);
}

function onOpen(e) { 
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('Test Menu')
      .addItem('Test', 'doTest')
      .addToUi();
}

function doTest() {
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService
  .createHtmlOutput('<p>Some Text</p>')
  .setTitle('My title');
  
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(htmlOutput);
}
```

The sidebar shows up correctly
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QTR8.png
But i get this error in the chrome console:

message: "There was an error during the transport or processing of this request. Error code = 10, Path = /wardeninit"

name: "TransportError"

stack:"TransportError: There was an error during the transport or processing of this request. Error code = 10, Path = /wardeninit
at new Qo (https://docs.google.com/static/macros/client/js/3949079914-warden_bin_i18n_warden__vi.js:200:381)
at Vo.w.Xc (https://docs.google.com/static/macros/client/js/3949079914-warden_bin_i18n_warden__vi.js:208:372)
at Cf (https://docs.google.com/static/macros/client/js/3949079914-warden_bin_i18n_warden__vi.js:79:228)
at Bf (https://docs.google.com/static/macros/client/js/3949079914-warden_bin_i18n_warden__vi.js:76:472)
at xf.A (https://docs.google.com/static/macros/client/js/3949079914-warden_bin_i18n_warden__vi.js:76:419)
at Cf (https://docs.google.com/static/macros/client/js/3949079914-warden_bin_i18n_warden__vi.js:79:228)
at Bf (https://docs.google.com/static/macros/client/js/3949079914-warden_bin_i18n_warden__vi.js:76:472)
at Vo. (https://docs.google.com/static/macros/client/js/3949079914-warden_bin_i18n_warden__vi.js:207:159)
at An (https://docs.google.com/static/macros/client/js/3949079914-warden_bin_i18n_warden__vi.js:165:294)
at Do (https://docs.google.com/static/macros/client/js/3949079914-warden_bin_i18n_warden__vi.js:200:262)"

I have been make some Google App script before but just get this error recently.
What am I doing wrong?

**Updated**
Because of this "TransportError", any "google.script.run" script will fail.
If i update the code like this:

```
function doTest() {
  var htmlOutput = 
  HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(htmlOutput);
}

function doSomething() {
  Logger.log('I was called!');
}
```

And the Index.html is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
    function onSuccess() {
       console.log("onSuccess");
    }
    
    function onFailure(error) {
       console.log("onFailure",error);
    }
      
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).withFailureHandler(onFailure).doSomething();
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

The onFailure will always be called and the error is empty.

**Update 2**
The problem with *"google.script.run" script will fail.*
only for google workspace account.
If I change to my personal gmail account and made the similar code, the problem does not happen.

Comment: 1) Is there a specific reason you are using onInstall() and onOpen()?  onOpen() is triggered anytime the document is opened.

Comment: 2) Errors show up in the console all of the time, often unrelated to your code.  If it isn't preventing your sidebar from working, I wouldn't be too concerned about it.  With the exception of the onInstall() function (not sure why that is there, but could be a legitimate reason), the code looks good.

Comment: I agree with @KrispinMiller I get that sort of thing all of the time.  I don't worry about it.

Comment: @KrispinMiller i have just updated the problem. Because of the "TransportError", any "google.script.run" script will fail

Comment: @Cooper Because of the "TransportError", any "google.script.run" script will fail

Comment: And this is the log on console [https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Avsa.png]

Comment: Well I can't reproduce the error, so it's rather difficult for me to help you.

Comment: I believe that the error that is passed to the function is an object and you need to access the message like this:    console.log("onFailure", error.message)  -  However, it has been awhile since I've dealt with this.

Comment: I can reproduce this if I log into my personal Google account, then log into my Workspace account and deploy the code there. I filed an [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/298799211), please upvote.

Answer (score 0):

I used your code like this:

html:(filename: ah3.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
    function onSuccess() {
       console.log("onSuccess");
    }
    function onFailure(error) {
       console.log("onFailure",error);
    }
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).withFailureHandler(onFailure).doSomething();
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>Hello World</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

gs:

```
function doTest() {
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('ah3').setTitle('My title');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(htmlOutput);
}

function doSomething() {
  Logger.log('I was called!');
}
```

It works for me.

If you look in the console you will see the `onSuccess` printed and if you look in executions you will see `Sep 3, 2021, 10:16:03 PM    Info    I was called!`

Comment: Not work @Cooper.
I made the code again just like you.

Comment: I open a new google sheet file, use Tool/ Script Editor to make new script but the problem still happens

Comment: i find a new problem. If i use a different gmail account (my personal account), the problem disappear. But if i change to the account of Google workspace, the problem happens again

Comment: If you have an admin on your workspace account, I'd speak with them about the problem.

Comment: @Cooper: I'm an admin on my own Workspace account, and I have no idea why this cryptic error occurs.

Comment: I just reloaded it and it works for me

Comment: @Cooper: I can reproduce this if I log into my personal Google account, then log into my Workspace account and deploy the code there. I filed an [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/298799211) with more details. Can you reproduce in those conditions?