# Having problems when opening my Add-on sidebar in Google Chrome and Edge

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm getting the following error when trying to open my Google Sheets Add-on in Google Chrome:

```
message: "There was an error during the transport or processing of this request. Error code = 10, Path = /wardeninit"
name: "TransportError"
```

However, when I open it on Firefox everything works correctly.
I looked at the same error message ([google.script.run throwing Transport error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64804171/google-script-run-throwing-transport-error)), but none of the solutions worked for my problem.

Hoping someone can help me with a hint.

Comment: Tried in incognito?

Comment: Not yet, I would check it out right now.

Comment: Now I did, and it is still failing.

Comment: Hey @Luisa Can you share your code? The question that you reference in your question already has an answer that points to the type of variable he was passing. However yours mentions it working on one explorer while not on others. Could you share also some of the logs? I'm sure more programmers would be able to help once more information is available.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @A.PerezCera: I posted a Google IssueTracker [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/298799211) with code that reproduces a similar problem. Apparently it's caused by the user being logged into multiple accounts.

Comment: @DanDascalescu You should post this as the answer to leave a clear record for others.